# Are there any constantly updating RSS feed services to use for testing, or just very active RSS feeds?

Tags: service, rss, feed

I'm trying to test a service that consumes RSS feeds and turns them into push notifications, and it would be nice if there was a very regularly updated publicly available RSS feed I could point it at.

I know I can just use a news feed like CNN, but I'm wondering if there's something more "Lorem Ipsum" style for RSS.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I really needed this service, so I set one up at http://lorem-rss.herokuapp.com/

The documentation is at that link, as well as in the GitHub repository below. You can tweak it using GET parameters to update every N seconds, minutes, hours, days, months or years. But I haven't yet tested it comprehensively so I'm not sure if the RSS validates well across different parsers. YMMV.

The code is on GitHub at https://github.com/mbertolacci/lorem-rss

Answer (score 6):

If you select a highly active feed (http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss) then the updates should be very frequent.

Be aware that some sites use different RSS versions so you might have to adjust your code as required.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's not bad, but still quite sporadic - updates range between 30 minutes and a few hours, but to facilitate a fast development cycle 30 seconds to a minute would be more helpful.

Comment: I would be using multiple RSS feed sites and then process the feed accordingly. I do this on my own site http://jeffnorth.com but I only require news to have happened in the last 7 days (that is why some buttons maybe greyed out) - nothing to process.

Answer (score 3):

Busy subreddits are the best option if you figure out how to get their RSS feed.
For example, here is one of them:
https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/new/.rss

For more information: https://www.reddit.com/wiki/rss